# How can I skip an after_filter callback based on my response status code in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback, http-status-codes

I have an after_filter in one of my controllers that I want to execute only if the response status code is 200. Otherwise I want to skip it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick and easy way is to put a conditional on your `after_filter` like this:

```
after_filter :do_something

def do_something
  if response.code == '200'
    # do something
  end
end
```

Comment: @camou According to the documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Response.html you can only set `status`, and only get `code`. So basically, the difference is the access, one is a getter and one is a setter.